# Missing required parameter: refresh_token node js

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I'm trying to download files from google drive using node js and google API,so I followed this quickstart : https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/nodejs.
but I get this error in the **listFiles** function :

*The API returned an error: Error: **invalid_request***

I tried to console log the res.data and I get this :

```
{
  error: 'invalid_request',
  error_description: 'Missing required parameter: refresh_token'
}
```

This is the listFiles function :

```
function listFiles(auth) {
    const drive = google.drive({version: 'v3', auth});
    drive.files.list({
      pageSize: 10,
      fields: 'nextPageToken, files(id, name)',
    }, (err, res) => {
      console.log('****************')
      console.log('****************')
      console.log(res.data)
      console.log('****************')
      console.log('****************')
      if (err) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
      const files = res.data.files;
      if (files.length) {
        console.log('Files:');
        files.map((file) => {
          console.log(`${file.name} (${file.id})`);
        });
      } else {
        console.log('No files found.');
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: how are you defining auth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a glance, it looks like something is amiss with the `auth` object you're passing in.  You may want to share some details on that code :) That aside - there is a fully functioning sample here in case you want to test out your service account credentials and the 3-legged OAuth flow:
https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/samples/drive/download.js